# Playing Audio/Video from UDP data in a Browser

Tags: html, audio, video

Now that FireFox has dropped their support for plugins, I have lost a huge feature on my website that integrated a VLC plugin for audio and for video from UDP data.

What are the best options (sticking to FireFox only is completely acceptable for my customer base) to get both audio and video data (as separate modules) into a browser from a UDP stream?

I was hoping Flash was a solution but it looks like their udp datagram api is not supported on the browser. VLC was the most convenient but now it is dead...

Comment: You can use as temporary solution Firefox ESR. I hope videoLAN folks be working on creating PPAPI plugin for Vlc.

Comment: `We are not going to extend NPAPI support on the release branch beyond the next ESR`

Comment: Firefox ESR will support NPAPI  but will eventually be deprecated in Firefox ESR 59.